# How can I access the index of the column in the ListView that I clicked?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a ListView with several columns. How can I access the index of the column in the ListView when its clicked?

Comment: Which technology ? WPF, WinForms, ASP.NET ?

Comment: Added [winforms] tag, since the answers are for WinForms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function that handles the click event, there are two arguments, `sender` and `e`.  `e` is the event arguments.  The members of `e` in any event-handling function will be objects having to do with the event that you are handling.

Therefore, look at the Intellisense for `e` to find data about which column you just clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the MouseEventArgs parameter to get the mouse position then feed that into HitTest() to get detailed information such as the actual row and column that were clicked. Here's the code:

```
private void myListView_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ListViewHitTestInfo hitItem = myListView.HitTest(e.Location);

    // hitItem now contains the item, subitem, row index and so on.
```